# How can I publish an R Markdown Shiny Dashboard privately?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

So for context, I have created a dashboard using Rstudio by using flexfdashboard. I is an R Markdown Shiny app with ui and source code all within the same file.

Data sources for this app are large, locally saved documents in. Txt and. Csv format, with sizes ranging from a few kilobytes to several gigabytes.

I am to present this work to my CEO but I will not have access to my current computer and so ideally would host my dashboard somewhere and simply load the dashboard in browser.

However, the datasets contain sensative customer information and so privacy or controlled access to all assets is essential, ruling out most 3rd party solutions.

Is there a simple method to achieve this that im missing, or will I have to just run it from a local machine?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad question. Do you have a Linux server where you could install Siny Server or RStudio Connect? Alternatively, you could try packaging the dashboard as a docker container or with https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR.